# Map Firebase database child to swift 3 object

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How dow I map the objects stored in a list in my firebase db to their corresponding objects in swift?

Right now the following isn't working:

```
for child in snapshot.children{
    let tempMed = child as Med
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly get custom object from `FIRDataSnapshot` what you do is create one `init` with your custom class or struct and use that to create object from `FIRDataSnapshot`.

Ex

```
struct Med {

    let title: String
    let desc: String
    init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String:Any], 
              let title = dic["title"] as? String,
              let desc = dic["description"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc
    }
}
```

Now get array of `Med` this way.

```
let meds = snapshot.children.flatMap { Med(snapshot: $0 as! FIRDataSnapshot)  }
```