# Map Data From Firestore to a struct In Swift - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

I'm trying to map a "user" retrieved from my Firestore database to a user struct I've defined in my code but I don't think I properly understand the mapping features in swift.

How do I go about mapping the user retrieved into the struct?

Struct

```
struct User {
// Properties

    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var userName: String
    var email: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, userName: String, email: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.userName = userName
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

Function that gets user from Firestore

```
func getUser(UID: String) {
    // Firebase setup
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    db.settings = settings

    db.collection("users").document(UID).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print(document!.data()!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but the `init` you provided in your `User` struct is unnecessary. You will get that same `init` automatically without having to write it yourself.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip! I didn't realize it was automatic. Do you happen to know how to do any of this mapping though @rmaddy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786471/map-firebase-database-child-to-swift-3-object What about this one?

Comment: That solution definitely works! But is there a way to do it using the mapping features in swift? Some of the database models I plan on building out will be much larger and more complicated. I also just want to learn how to use these features for future reference @emrepun

Comment: You may want to make your struct conform to `Codable` protocol (`Encodable & Decodable`). If your struct is only strings you won't have to implement anything, just conform to that protocol and it's done, otherwise, if you have subobjects in you're `User` struct, you will have to write your own parsing. With this you can use the dictionary in the snapshot to build the `User`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what the expected result is from *mapping the user*? In other words, document.data is a dictionary of key: value pairs - your current code doesn't address getting to that data so what's the use case?

Comment: @VladRusu The document retrieved from Firestore will be a [String: Any] dictionary which doesn't conform to Encoder, it's not a JSON object. Would you solution still work without any other code?

Comment: @Jay In this case you have to cast to `[String: String]`, but it only works if you have strings only. Otherwise you will have to translate the `Dictionary` into `Data`. You can do this using `NSJSONSerialization` instead of `JSONDecoder` which only accepts `Decodable`s

Comment: @Jay The expected result is for me to be able to get a user from firebase, map it to a User and store it as a variable in my code, let's call it `retrievedUser`, and then access the properties of that user such as `retrievedUser.lastName` and do as I please with it.

Comment: @VladRusu I've heard of that method, but isn't there a way to simply use `compactMap` or `flatMap` to do this?

Comment: @yambo I'm afraid not :( Or at least i don't know about any of that. As long as you have mixed types, you have to use `[String: Any]` for the JSON dictionary, which will give you a lot of headaches. Up until now, the best solution I know for the `[String: Any]` issue is the good old `NSJSONSerialization` which does not require the dictionary to have `Decodable` generic types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A queried Firestore document is of type `[String: Any]`, so configure your initializer to accept that kind of dictionary. Because you're working with a database return, there is never a guarantee that the data will be fully intact, so I would suggest making your initializer failable, which just means that it can return `nil` (it can fail).

I took your example and made the `email` property optional. In the example below, only three of the four properties are necessary to instantiate the `User` object.

```
let info: [String: Any] = ["hasFriends": true]
let firestoreData: [String: Any] = ["firstName": "lance", "lastName": "stevenson", "userName": "lstevenson", "info": info]

struct User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var userName: String
    var info: [String: Any]
    var email: String?
    var hasFriends: Bool
    
    init?(data: [String: Any]) {
        guard let firstName = data["firstName"] as? String,
            let lastName = data["lastName"] as? String,
            let userName = data["userName"] as? String,
            let info = data["info"] as? [String: Any],
            let hasFriends = info["hasFriends"] as? Bool else {
                return nil
        }
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.userName = userName
        self.info = info
        self.hasFriends = hasFriends
        self.email = data["email"] as? String // User will be created even if this is nil
    }
}

if let user = User(data: firestoreData) {
    print(user.hasFriends) // true
}
```

I would not suggest that you use Swift's mapping tool for this because you will likely be dealing with varying types of values within the same dictionary for different models. And the code to map this dictionary with those variables in an initializer would not be pretty.

Comment: This solution works very well, I would have never even thought of it! But let's say in my firebase database I have an "info" property, that is itself a dictionary of different types. For instance, it has a dictionary containing the users list of friends within it, as well as different properties such as boolean values, etc. How would I access specific properties returned from this nested property within swift?

Comment: I updated my answer. Copy and paste that into a Playground and play around with it until you're comfortable.

Comment: This works amazingly! I'm new to coding as you can probably tell, so is it standard practice to make every property optional, since in theory the database call could return partial data as you said?

Comment: That’s one thing to consider. Another thing to consider is if you made them all optional and they were all/mostly nil, would you really have any use of that user object? Would your UI be better off just discarding that user and getting the next one? We’re also dealing with Google; reliability doesn’t get much higher. But the decision is ultimately yours, as the engineer. What makes most sense to you? Personally, I will assume that Firebase and the network will deliver 99.x% of the time so I wouldn’t make them all optional, but I will keep the initializer failable as a general safety net.

Comment: I feel using a nil coalescing operator would be more appropriate rather then failing the entire user if some value is missing. For example: `self.firstName = firstName ?? "ERR"`